How can I handle transactions across multiple containers in GridDB?
I am working on a project using GridDB and need to manage transactions across multiple containers. Specifically, I want to ensure that if one operation fails, all changes in the transaction are rolled back. For example, if I insert data into Container1 and Container2, and an error occurs in one of the containers, I want the changes in both containers to be rolled back.
I am unsure if GridDB supports multi-container transactions natively or if I need to handle this manually to ensure consistency. Can someone explain the best approach to handle this situation?
I have tried using GridDB’s transaction API to manage a transaction across two containers. However, when an error occurred in one of the insert operations, the changes in the other container were not rolled back, which caused data inconsistency. I was expecting GridDB to automatically manage the rollback of both containers in case of failure, but this didn’t happen. How should I handle multi-container transactions in GridDB to ensure consistency?
